# can i omit atom:link in odata feed with null or empty relation

Tags: wcf, odata, atom-feed

Am i correct in reading that if an element is null or a collection empty and the request did not specify to inline ("m:inline") the attached property that it is then acceptable to omit the atom:link entry entirely?

I am one of the two core developers on the POData project over at https://github.com/algo-web/POData and we'd appreciate a third party checking our understanding of the OData specification. The specific extracts are as follows

> 2.2.6.2.2 Entity Type (as an Atom Entry Element)
>
> In OData 3.0, responses to retrieve requests, as specified in
> RetrieveEntity Request (section 2.2.7.2.2), MAY represent the URI that
> identifies the association between the entity represented by the
> response payload and a related entity (or collection of entities) as
> an atom:link element that is a child element of the atom:entry
> element. If present, each atom:link element MUST contain a rel
> attribute with the value defined by the relAssociationlLinkURI rule
> shown in the grammar defined in the listing that follows. The element
> MUST also contain an href attribute with a value equal to the URI that
> identifies the association represented by the atom:link element (that
> is, the NavigationProperty on the EntityType).

and

> 2.2.6.2.6.1 Inline Representation
>
> If NavigationProperty represents an EntityType instance and that
> instance is null, an empty m:inline element MUST appear under the
> atom:link element that represents NavigationProperty. If
> NavigationProperty represents a collection of entities and the
> collection is empty, an m:inline element with a nested atom:Feed
> element with no atom:Entry subelements MUST appear under the atom:link
> element that represents NavigationProperty. In both cases, the
> presence of the m:inline element indicates that NavigationProperty has
> been expanded but that no content was associated with it.

Both sections from "[2.2.6.2 AtomPub Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541369.aspx)"

Am I correct in reading that if an element is null (or a collection is empty) and the request did not specifically request that the attached property be inlined, then it's acceptable to leave the atom:link entry for that specific property out completely?

In other words, if an element is null/empty and not specifically requested (by asking that it be inlined), then I can simplly leave its corresponding link out?